# CocosDension crashing on Windows when I close the application

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-x

When I close my application on Windows. Sometimes it's throwing `Access violation writing location` inside the destructor of **MciPlayer.cpp** class

```
MciPlayer::~MciPlayer() {
Close();
DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);
}
```

The app is crashing sometimes on `DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);`. I have no idea why it's occurring?

I am using **cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4** on **Windows 7 x86**

Comment: is your windows created via cocos2d or you used only Dension? Just cocos2d-x windows autoreleasing objects, so is there sense to destroy it like you did?

Comment: Yes it's created via cocos2dx.

Answer (score 0):

In file 'CCEGLView.cpp', 'DestroyWindow(m_hWnd)'will be called in function CCEGLView::end(). So,make sure that you did not destroy it twice.

```
if(m_hWnd)
{
    DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);
    m_hWnd = NULL;
}
```